# MEAN - Cannot find name 'Map' (when compiling server)

Tags: angular, express, typescript

I written a server for my angular 2 app in TypeScript.

When I try to compile it (`tsc server.ts`), I get an error. I never had this error before. I don't think I have added anything new. And what I know, there is no connection at all with angular 2 and my server.ts. I'm kinda out of options. All answers I found was  about adding something to a angular 2 file.

Error message:

```
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(28,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
```

I don't know what is relevant to show, so if you don't mind - please ask for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have typescript definition files of map, so :

```
npm install @types/core-js
```

Comment: Hm.. It worked before. When I ran that command I got some new errors. 

I now have duplicates of promises. " Duplicate identifier 'Promise'."

/@types/es6-promise and /@types/core-js

Comment: @types/core-js module contains all typescript definitions of ecmascript6

Comment: yes promises are defined in the @types/core-js so delete it : `npm uninstall @types/es6-promise`

Comment: It worked! But I can't understand why it worked for the past week. I have not added anything new. And it's impossible for you to answer.

Comment: hhh I'don't know , don't forget to mark my answer as solution ;)